# How to update only specific field in object within an array Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Expense Tracker application : Nodejs, Mongodb

Trying to Create a function that will update only the passed fields from request inside an array of objects

Database Schema

[image: Database Schema]

```
const updateExpense = async (req, res) => {
try {
    let db = mongo.getDb()
    let { macro, micro, amount, note } = req.body;
    let { username, id } = req.query
    let expense = await db.collection("Expense").updateOne({ username: username, "expenses.expense_id": ObjectId(id) }, { $set: { 
        "expenses.$.macro": macro,
        "expenses.$.micro": micro,
        "expenses.$.amount": amount,
        "expenses.$.note": note }
     });
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Expense Updated",
        expense: expense
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
        message: err.message
    });
}
}
```

**The above function is replacing all other fields with null**

If the user is passing only the micro field, then the other fields should remain the same and only the micro field should change and other fields should not change.

*Need A MongoDB Query which will only change what is required based on the data passed in req*

Answer (score 0):

I think you must first fetch from the database with `findOne` then update that fields set in `req.body`, something like this:

```js
const updateExpense = async (req, res) => {
try {
    let db = mongo.getDb()
    let { macro, micro, amount, note } = req.body;
    let { username, id } = req.query
    let expense = await db.collection("Expense").findOne({ username: username });
    let special_ex = expense.expenses.find(ex => ex.expense_id === ObjectId(id);
    special_ex.macro = macro ? macro : special_ex.macro;
    special_ex.micro = micro ? micro : special_ex.micro;

/*
    and so on ...
*/    

    await expense.update();

    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Expense Updated",
        expense: expense
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
        message: err.message
    });
}
}
```